# DataGridView doesn't refresh properly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have been having some trouble with a DataGridView in a windows form app. I have it preset with the columns and every so often I need to update the data in the rows. Instead of trying to update each row manually, I just wanted to clear out all the existing rows and add new ones with the new data. My code is as below:

```
private void RefreshPlayerStatus()
{
    gridPlayers.Rows.Clear();
    List<object[]> playerInfo = game.GetPlayerInfo();
    foreach (object[] info in playerInfo)
       gridPlayers.Rows.Add(info);
    gridPlayers.Refresh();
}
```

For some reason, the grid is cleared but the new rows do not appear. I've looked at other answers, resetting the dataBindings and sources but that didn't help, guessing because I never use a data source. If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Made the dataGridView bound to the new `PlayerInfo` class which has all the properties for my view. When running the modified method below, the grid still empties but does not display the new information.

```
private void RefreshPlayerStatus()
{
    List<PlayerInfo> playerInfo = mafiaGame.GetPlayerInfo();
    gridPlayers.DataSource = playerInfo;
    gridPlayers.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Resetting bindings is irrelevant if the grid is not bound.  Is it?  Your code would suggest not.  I would suggest that it probably should be but that's not essential.  What is your data actually comprised of?  Using `Object` arrays is a pretty bad idea.  Surely you can get the data in a far more specific form than that, e.g. instances of a class with properties of type `String`, etc.  You can then bind a list of such objects to your grid.  You can then simply bind a new list to the grid at any time, replacing all the old data in a single line of code.

Comment: When adding rows like this, the object[] info in the foreach loop has to match your columns. Could you post the code where you initially add the rows/columns to your grid ?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I create a class PlayerInfo that has properties for all the fields as strings and bound the DataGridView to that class. I now pass a list to the grid instead, as shown in the edit above. But after the initial call, whenever the method is run again, still nothing shows up in the grid